# Keycloak SSO Session Idle always set to 30 minutes

Tags: session, timeout, single-sign-on, keycloak

I'm working on a project with the latest Keycloak version, Spring Boot and Spring Oauth2 and Angular as the frontend layer.

Here is my keycloak token configuration:

[image]

Whatever value I set for property "SSO Session Idle" on my kecloak server, I end up with a RFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR after 30 minutes (That is the default value for this property based on the official documentation) and after that I can't call any backend endpoint anymore, my token has been invalidated and all calls are made with an Anonymous Authentication object.

What should I do to make this property work (In my case it shouldn't invalidate the token before 10 hours) ?
Do I have somehow to refresh the token from frontend side to avoid my token being invalidated ?
How should I handle the client inactivity timeout so as users don't have to log in again every 30 minutes ?

Any help or example would be highly appreciated.

Advanced settings for the client on keycloak server:
[client settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJhsb.png)

Comment: No, I'm not overriding these values in the client configuration, SSO Session Idle is also set to 10 hours

Comment: Exp time is +10 hours based on the current time which is correct based on property "Access token lifespan". The token is still valid when session timeout comes up after 30 minutes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify refresh tokens lifespan in Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040265/how-to-specify-refresh-tokens-lifespan-in-keycloak) Please read also comment of accepted answer - it's complicated.

Comment: @LionelB I am facing similar issue, could you please confirm what solved this issue for you?

Comment: Are you sure that the keycloak session is the one that times out ? The spring session usually also has a default lifespan of 30 minutes. It could be that this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue from Client Side. After Refreshing Tokens in Client Side I was able to solve the issue. I used the following code. This could help. Kindly check.

```
keycloak.onTokenExpired = () => {
   console.log(">>> Re-Authenticated");
   keycloak.updateToken(50);
};
```