# How do I generate short lived service account access tokens in Keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak, service-accounts, keycloak-services

I am generating an access token for a service account as described in the Keycloak docs. As an example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://my.domain/auth/realms/aRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YXBcnZlcjpNlpuMwRWk1Y02ZFRE15vVp2YUdHJibmNalVvMFmxzVNQVg==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

I do get a token back, but it expires in 30 mins, just as I have configured them in my realm settings, for normal users usage.

But for the use as a service account, I do not want such a long lived token.  Even 10-15 secs should be enough to generate the token and then immediately make a request to the server.

I have seen a similar feature in Google auth docs (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct#rest_2) by passing a `lifetime` param, where you ask for tokens with a specific lifetime.

Keycloak docs (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_service_accounts) do not mention anything about shorter living tokens.  Have I missed a section that mentions something like that?  Or is there an alternative way to create short lived tokens?

EDIT:

> The Keycloak client created is used by users to logging to the system.
> For that usecase, I want their token to be valid for 30mins before
> they have to be refreshed again. But for service accounts usage (when
> I want my distributed code to make an API request to my own servers) I
> want these tokens to have a very short lived lifetime (enough to just
> make the API call).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirements, I am under the impression that you are mixing concerns and different authentication flows.

> The Keycloak client created is used by users to logging to the system.
> For that use-case, I want their token to be valid for 30mins before
> they have to be refreshed again.

Without knowing more details about your application, this use-case is typically solved by using a ***public client***. That client would typically use Standard flow, Implicit Flow or Direct Access Grants enabled (not recommended). If possible preferably using Standard flow. Those flows can be used with a *confidential client* as well -- as long as the secret is stored safely in the backend -- however, it is not *very natural*, and unnecessary.

The **Service Accounts** flow (*i.e.*, client credentials in OAuth2 terminology) forces the use of a *confidential client*. Hence, the use of the *client_secret* parameter in the request.

So there we start to see conflicts between best practices and the requirements that you have stated.

IMO the cleanest solution is to have a *public client* that is used by your users to authenticate normally, using the appropriate flow for that. In that client, you would set the 30 minutes as the token lifespan. And for:

> But for service accounts usage (when I want my distributed code to
> make an API request to my own servers) I want these tokens to have a
> very short lived lifetime (enough to just make the API call).

For that use-case, use a different client, *a confidential one*, with the Service Account flow enabled. Go to the client `Advanced Settings` menu and set the `Access Token Lifespan` to 1 minute for example. This value will override the value set at the Realm Level (actually, [in practice in can be more complicated than that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67624190/1366871)). The smallest time granularity that you can choose is minutes, for seconds you would have to use the approach showcased by [@Bench Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73003406/1366871).

Answer (score 0):

You can change a "access.token.lifespan" for specific client by PUT HTTP call.

PUT call **http://my.domain/auth/realms/aRealm/clients/client-id**

The Bearer token needs to get by admin with **realms-manage** role (or master admin, **manage-clients**)

[image]
This is example
my.domain : **http://localhost:8180**

aRealm : **test**

client id : **a6654164-d2f5-451d-8f8c-25f00f29eec5**

"access.token.lifespan": **15**

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/test/clients/a6654164-d2f5-451d-8f8c-25f00f29eec5' \
--header 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
--header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJSQjNmSzRrSC1EWmxjLWQ0ZjB3b3JJM3c5d0ZEY0RidFZTS0xmTlJlcVVRIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2NTgwMDEzNjEsImlhdCI6MTY1Nzk2NTM2MSwianRpIjoiNGU4NzRhZWMtMGVjZC00MjEyLThiYmUtNGUxODM2OTRlMGM5IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MTgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6ImFiOWNkMjc3LWFhYWEtNGI1My1iMzdlLTBhNzJiODZmZWI0OSIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiI2YjU5MTNlMC1lOGFkLTQzM2MtOTkyOC1lNTBjMjQ0MGNmN2MiLCJhY3IiOiIxIiwic2NvcGUiOiJlbWFpbCBwcm9maWxlIiwic2lkIjoiNmI1OTEzZTAtZThhZC00MzNjLTk5MjgtZTUwYzI0NDBjZjdjIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiJ9.LhOegp1UbzaWOrNWb5aKhIzatIvNNg0JPbZeKqnumJ2pdZKL3xTei2Uo6GPKg_YRp9G-YAuCVrQFNWbhP1fDBrDbAEvZHT0Ho4OmlysISFIGP3i9Hr1x3uILLPxGks0iiP7RzCiSubtIwNZRl3nro5bRXkEx24F1drD4hWKW95Z9VAFPkSUW3Urk5Hdgm991pUwUdQCPiyyNj7RL2uiHEsSEoypoT2CviZ518dElmnNFmPafg5K_j39atHX5DxwxEvT5cTfgD6Sg3CmrJupE3CfY31N8OfkmBCA__3mOx31btncK4uG9EsYujxSeHxEZhPV0gUwCx7ZykYkfKhl0OQ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "id": "a6654164-d2f5-451d-8f8c-25f00f29eec5",
  "clientId": "my-test-client",
  "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
  "enabled": true,
  "alwaysDisplayInConsole": false,
  "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
  "redirectUris": [
    "http://localhost:8180/test/*"
  ],
  "webOrigins": [],
  "notBefore": 0,
  "bearerOnly": false,
  "consentRequired": false,
  "standardFlowEnabled": true,
  "implicitFlowEnabled": false,
  "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true,
  "serviceAccountsEnabled": true,
  "authorizationServicesEnabled": true,
  "publicClient": false,
  "frontchannelLogout": false,
  "protocol": "openid-connect",
  "attributes": {
    "access.token.lifespan": 15,
    "saml.multivalued.roles": "false",
    "saml.force.post.binding": "false",
    "frontchannel.logout.session.required": "false",
    "oauth2.device.authorization.grant.enabled": "false",
    "backchannel.logout.revoke.offline.tokens": "false",
    "saml.server.signature.keyinfo.ext": "false",
    "use.refresh.tokens": "true",
    "oidc.ciba.grant.enabled": "false",
    "backchannel.logout.session.required": "true",
    "client_credentials.use_refresh_token": "false",
    "saml.client.signature": "false",
    "require.pushed.authorization.requests": "false",
    "saml.allow.ecp.flow": "false",
    "saml.assertion.signature": "false",
    "id.token.as.detached.signature": "false",
    "client.secret.creation.time": "1657583810",
    "saml.encrypt": "false",
    "saml.server.signature": "false",
    "exclude.session.state.from.auth.response": "false",
    "saml.artifact.binding": "false",
    "saml_force_name_id_format": "false",
    "tls.client.certificate.bound.access.tokens": "false",
    "acr.loa.map": "{}",
    "saml.authnstatement": "false",
    "display.on.consent.screen": "false",
    "token.response.type.bearer.lower-case": "false",
    "saml.onetimeuse.condition": "false",
    "request.uris": null,
    "frontchannel.logout.url": null,
    "default.acr.values": null,
    "oauth2.device.polling.interval": null
  },
  "authenticationFlowBindingOverrides": {},
  "fullScopeAllowed": true,
  "nodeReRegistrationTimeout": -1,
  "protocolMappers": [
    {
      "id": "fc55831d-9f85-4db5-8340-38e246fcfdf0",
      "name": "Client ID",
      "protocol": "openid-connect",
      "protocolMapper": "oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper",
      "consentRequired": false,
      "config": {
        "user.session.note": "clientId",
        "id.token.claim": "true",
        "access.token.claim": "true",
        "claim.name": "clientId",
        "jsonType.label": "String"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "8e7e2a2c-90be-41a0-8a75-87099184a4a4",
      "name": "Client IP Address",
      "protocol": "openid-connect",
      "protocolMapper": "oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper",
      "consentRequired": false,
      "config": {
        "user.session.note": "clientAddress",
        "id.token.claim": "true",
        "access.token.claim": "true",
        "claim.name": "clientAddress",
        "jsonType.label": "String"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bee09b85-a3db-471a-aa51-9f1504df0a6f",
      "name": "Client Host",
      "protocol": "openid-connect",
      "protocolMapper": "oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper",
      "consentRequired": false,
      "config": {
        "user.session.note": "clientHost",
        "id.token.claim": "true",
        "access.token.claim": "true",
        "claim.name": "clientHost",
        "jsonType.label": "String"
      }
    }
  ],
  "defaultClientScopes": [
    "web-origins",
    "acr",
    "roles",
    "profile",
    "email"
  ],
  "optionalClientScopes": [
    "address",
    "phone",
    "offline_access",
    "microprofile-jwt"
  ],
  "access": {
    "view": true,
    "configure": true,
    "manage": true
  }
}'
```

you can check it's value by GET HTTP call
The **"expires_in":15** tell how much the **lifetime**

In here, that value is 15 seconds. It should be match as I sent by PUT call.

```
  curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/test/clients/a6654164-d2f5-451d-8f8c-25f00f29eec5' \
> --header 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
> --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
> --header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
> --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJMWkdvVDZ6WFdtMU5BNmh2WXhlbUFrVmFaQWJodnlmWlo4Q2JqRWJ0U3RrIn0.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.hjWKdTzSTjJpfW2hRqDOTML_5Uo2s5glAEDzVE567huW0LdYNtElvoi_wdLXNsYwCcVgW8juHsRHdoTlljT91zoZeY9VFg1YUJCF6k6uEkZXgSKvhm87jiyPMQa1Ex_b7wmOza0SFrhz3--PVMKgV6EJ2R1GtbwXfwQeLxsKslaIvjgAIliHNlIkxOA9bTnyFwOpvv93km1E9S3KjExcN1jq-KptslSa8lY35ExyCIatWbu_g9nrWlcQGg14qM8VfcJhrmL4ZDb0uaBk8HbZ52RNU8qu2pB584TsZ5iR29afRF5jTY-3pRiKUnTTOnQDrKLkqPvLhVwJPiRABcClDw'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2910  100  2910    0     0   265k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  284k{"id":"a6654164-d2f5-451d-8f8c-25f00f29eec5","clientId":"my-test-client","surrogateAuthRequired":false,"enabled":true,"alwaysDisplayInConsole":false,"clientAuthenticatorType":"client-secret","redirectUris":["http://localhost:8180/test/*"],"webOrigins":[],"notBefore":0,"bearerOnly":false,"consentRequired":false,"standardFlowEnabled":true,"implicitFlowEnabled":false,"directAccessGrantsEnabled":true,"serviceAccountsEnabled":true,"authorizationServicesEnabled":true,"publicClient":false,"frontchannelLogout":false,"protocol":"openid-connect","attributes":{"access.token.lifespan":"15","saml.multivalued.roles":"false","saml.force.post.binding":"false","frontchannel.logout.session.required":"false","oauth2.device.authorization.grant.enabled":"false","backchannel.logout.revoke.offline.tokens":"false","saml.server.signature.keyinfo.ext":"false","use.refresh.tokens":"true","oidc.ciba.grant.enabled":"false","backchannel.logout.session.required":"true","client_credentials.use_refresh_token":"false","saml.client.signature":"false","require.pushed.authorization.requests":"false","saml.allow.ecp.flow":"false","saml.assertion.signature":"false","id.token.as.detached.signature":"false","client.secret.creation.time":"1657583810","saml.encrypt":"false","saml.server.signature":"false","exclude.session.state.from.auth.response":"false","saml.artifact.binding":"false","saml_force_name_id_format":"false","tls.client.certificate.bound.access.tokens":"false","acr.loa.map":"{}","saml.authnstatement":"false","display.on.consent.screen":"false","token.response.type.bearer.lower-case":"false","saml.onetimeuse.condition":"false"},"authenticationFlowBindingOverrides":{},"fullScopeAllowed":true,"nodeReRegistrationTimeout":-1,"protocolMappers":[{"id":"fc55831d-9f85-4db5-8340-38e246fcfdf0","name":"Client ID","protocol":"openid-connect","protocolMapper":"oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper","consentRequired":false,"config":{"user.session.note":"clientId","id.token.claim":"true","access.token.claim":"true","claim.name":"clientId","jsonType.label":"String"}},{"id":"8e7e2a2c-90be-41a0-8a75-87099184a4a4","name":"Client IP Address","protocol":"openid-connect","protocolMapper":"oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper","consentRequired":false,"config":{"user.session.note":"clientAddress","id.token.claim":"true","access.token.claim":"true","claim.name":"clientAddress","jsonType.label":"String"}},{"id":"bee09b85-a3db-471a-aa51-9f1504df0a6f","name":"Client Host","protocol":"openid-connect","protocolMapper":"oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper","consentRequired":false,"config":{"user.session.note":"clientHost","id.token.claim":"true","access.token.claim":"true","claim.name":"clientHost","jsonType.label":"String"}}],"defaultClientScopes":["web-origins","acr","roles","profile","email"],"optionalClientScopes":["address","phone","offline_access","microprofile-jwt"],"access":{"view":true,"configure":true,"manage":true}}
```