# Keycloak session and token timeouts

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am developing an application with Keycloak as the authN service.

I would like to configure my application so that an access token has a 5 minute validity, a user will be logged out after 14 days of inactivity, and a user can remained logged on indefinitely as long as there is activity at least every 14 days.

In my realm settings, under "Access Token Lifespan" I have 5 minutes.
In the Sessions tab, the SSO Session Idle is set to 14 days.
In the same tab, the SSO Session Max is set to 9999 days.

When I log in with the password grant, I get an access token with an expiration 9999 days away and an refresh token with an expiration 9999 days away. I expected an access token with an expiration 5 minutes out and a refresh token with an expiration 14 days out.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6):

> When I log in with the password grant, I get an access token with an
> expiration 9999 days away and an refresh token with an expiration 9999
> days away. I expected an access token with an expiration 5 minutes out
> and a refresh token with an expiration 14 days out.

Your expectation is correct; more details on why can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67624190/1366871).

It seems to be some kind of bug (overflow maybe?!) on the Keycloak side. If you used 999 days instead of 9999 days, the access token will be 5 minutes and the refresh token will be 14 days has you expected.

From my tests on Keycloak 18 you can go until 5419 days without any problem.

Today is `19/03/2023` and 5420 days from now is `19/01/2038` so basically seems to me to be a manifestation of the [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are making all of these changes in the same realm as to which you are logging-in.