# Keycloak: User needs to login every day altough refresh token is set to 30 days

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, access-token, refresh-token

as explained in [How to specify refresh tokens lifespan in Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040265/how-to-specify-refresh-tokens-lifespan-in-keycloak) I set the following values in my realm to extend the lifespan of the refresh token:

- SSO Session Idle: 30 days
- SSO Session Max:  30 days
- Client Session Idle: 30 days
- Client Session Max: 30 days

But still my customer is complaining that he needs to log in every day.

I am I missing any other configuration, in order to not have the user loging everyday?

I did not change the default value for access token.

Thanks!